# ordering of legend of a scatterplot in ggplot and adjusting the title of that legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
p = ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = Auckland, aes(x = Date, y = Value, colour = "Auckland"),size=1) +
  geom_line(data = Wellington, aes(x = Date, y = Value, colour = "Wellington"),size =1) +
    geom_line(data = Canterbury, aes(x = Date, y = Value, colour = "Canterbury"),size =1)+
    geom_line(data = Otago, aes(x = Date, y = Value, colour = "Otago"),size =1) +
 xlab("Period") +
  ylab("rent per week (NZD)")+
  labs(title= "Weekly rent in NZ regions over time")
print(p)
```

[image]

I'm wondering how to change the order of the legend list
I'm thinking somewhere along the lines of this

```
(breaks = c("Auckland", "Wellington", "Canterbury", "Otago"))
#this is the order I want descending
```

For background information Auckland, Wellington, Canterbury and Otago come from four different dataframes and some of the other examples with fixing legend order come from one dataframe only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a programming question site; not a homework answering site [ask]. Please consider including a sample of your data, what code you have tried out, your expected outcome, and the problem(s) you have. [mre] gives guidance on question content which will help elicit an answer.
[Stackoverflow discussion on homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: `ggplot` tends to work better with a single data frame---I'd strongly recommend combining your data. If you need help with that, please share a little bit of sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
library(tidyverse)
Auckland <- Auckland %>% mutate(region = "Auckland")
Wellington <- Wellington %>% mutate(region = "Wellington")
Canterbury <- Canterbury %>% mutate(region = "Canterbury")
Otago <- Otago %>% mutate(region = "Otago")

bind_rows(Auckland, Wellington, Canterbury, Otago) %>% 
  mutate(region = factor(region, levels = c("Auckland", "Wellington", "Canterbury", "Otago"))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Value, colour = region), size = 1) +
  labs(title = "Weekly rent in NZ regions over time", 
       x = "Period", 
       y = "Rent per week (NZD)", 
       colour = "Region")
```

Comment: The repeated `mutate(region =` is a little clunky, I'd suggest `list(Auckland, Wellington, Canterbury, "Otago") %>% setNames("Auckland", "Wellington", "Canterbury", "Otago") %>% bind_rows(.id = "region") %>% mutate(region = forcats::fct_inorder(region)) %>% ...` as an alternative. But what a nice first answer, welcome to (posting on) the site!